# Comment posted while writing comment notification bar popup

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, comments

I don't know if this bothers anyone else, but when I am writing a comment on a new or hot item, and others are doing the same, it often ends up that duplicate comments are posted.

It would be nice if the notification bar came up after someone posted a comment on the same item while your comment was in edit. Or at least if someone posted a comment, it was loaded automatically. At the moment I believe I have to reload the page to see any comments posted while I was writing mine.

Is anyone else bothered by this or is it too minor a nuisance?

Comment: `is it too minor a nuisance?` -> This.

Comment: why don't you simply delete your comment if you realize that you've duplicated someone else's?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think its far too minor to bother. Real duplicate comments are normally rather short ones, so it doesn't make a big difference if you cancel it after writing for 5 seconds after being notified of the other comment, or if you delete it after 10 seconds when you posted it and realize there is already another one.

Additionally, if there would be a notification bar like the one from the answers, you are writing your comment, the bar shows up, you click on the bar to show the new comment, you see it is NO duplicate ==> in this time you could have finished your comment if you where not distracted by the notification bar.

So I think the distraction would be worse than the benefit.

If you invested more time and used all 600 characters, the chance is very good that its not a duplicate.